# After update the display resolution changed automatically to 1024x768 and no alternative resolutions available

Tags: nvidia, updates, display-resolution, 20.04

After installing updates and rebooting my display resolution was 1024x768 and there is no option in the drop-down menu to change it to another resolution, resulting in a poor display.

A partial fix is already in the answers: installing another display driver (either proprietary or noveau one), but the problem keeps recurring after new system updates. A root cause and permanent fix is sought.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after I installed Ubuntu 20.04 . To resolve the issue, I 
when to "Software & Updates" --> "Additional Drivers" .

My computer was using Nouveau display driver.  I changed it to Nvidia and my resolution went back  4k.

[image: Additional drivers screen print]

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case this tab is just empty... no drivers available (AMD RX580), very strange

Comment: This solved my problem but in reverse. Was using nvidia drivers 450 and 460 when this problem arised, reverting to noveau drivers solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, I just had to open Software and Updates, and a message poped up regarding "Partial updates" (first time I saw that), which probably internally did this! It fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I was using an older driver listed as (proprietary), so I switched to the newest one listed as (proprietary, tested) and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

### The same here with Xubuntu 20.04

Everything was fine after the installation. It is a new installation, not an upgrade.

Suddenly, after a couple of hours of use, the display just switched to 1024x768, following a logout (it was not the first time I logged out).

**My hardware and driver configurations**

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS780L [Radeon 3000]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:d000(size=256)
       memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff memory:fe800000-fe8fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ modprobe --resolve-alias radeon

radeon
```

```
$ sudo modinfo -F filename `lshw -c video | \
awk '/configuration: driver/{print $2}' | cut -d= -f2`

/lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
```

### My (still) incomplete solution

I executed `cvt` to get the right modeline info for my VGA monitor. I had read the monitor's manual to get the specifications

```
$ cvt 1440 900 60

# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz 
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Then I created the following shell script `/some-path/mydisplay.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1440x900_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

Make it executable

```
$ sudo chmod a+x  /some-path/mydisplay.sh
```

Now run the script, and hopefully the resolution will be back to normal

```
$ sudo /some-path/mydisplay.sh
```

### Still unsolved: make it permanent

I still couldn't make this solution persistent. Sometimes, after a logout or a restart, the display just goes back to 1024x768 mode. I don't find a pattern here.

Since Xubuntu 20.04 uses `lightdm`, I added the following lines yo my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`  file; and also to a new config file I created: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_mydisplay.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=/some-path/mydisplay.sh
user-session=mydisplay
allow-guest=false
```

I don't even know if these conf files are suitable for lightdm in Xubuntu 20.04.

I will appreciate any help regarding where is the right place to define permanently the right modeline configurations for Xubuntu 20.04 with lightdm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it sorted this way:
went to **software and updates > additional drivers**

- **changed driver to noveau and restarted** (the screen came back flickering but with the correct resolution)
- **Changed the driver back to the latest nvidia(460)** and it prompted a few windows to setup an "enroll MOK" during boot to allow those specific 3rd party drivers to work. **Just followed the steps, rebooted**
- During boot it prompted a few windows where **I just followed the steps, typed the password** I created on the previous step and that was it. It is working normally now.

UBUNTU 20.10/NVidia GeForce GT 1030

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and mucking around I found this command solution which returned my 1920x1080 resolution. Unfortunately I lost track of where I found it but this was the critical step...

apt install nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with an ASUS 2560x1440 monitor.  Originally the resolution was detected correctly, but I temporarily switched to a different monitor, and when I reconnected to my ASUS the only resolution that was allowed was 1024x768.  I followed the same steps as Rom above:

1. Change driver to Nouveau, reboot, resolution came up correctly
2. Change driver back to Nvidia (470 now the latest), reboot, resolution again is proper.